# Cancelling async tasks with semaphoreslim takes too long

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, semaphore, cancellation-token

Scenario is to queue tons of tasks of various kinds, throttle them for parallel processing, and be able to cancel them.
My problem is that cancelling them actually takes longer than the tasks themselves, due to all tasks already hanging in semaphore.

Obviously, the .Run throws all tasks into the .WaitAsync, and are therefor having status WaitingForActiviation. So the token given to the task itself is in fact pointless: All 1000 tasks are already running.

Giving the token to WaitAsync seems to freeze the application on cancel.

```cs
static SemaphoreSlim batcher = new SemaphoreSlim(5);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            var tokenStore = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i => 
                DoableWork(tokenStore.Token)
            ).ToList();

            do {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelling tasks");
                    tokenStore.Cancel();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"Tasks: {string.Join(", ", tasks.GroupBy(t => t.Status).Select(x => $"{x.Count()} {x.Key}"))}");
            } while (tasks.Any(t => t.Status < TaskStatus.RanToCompletion));
        }

        private static Task DoableWork(CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Run(async () => {
                try {
                    await batcher.WaitAsync();
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    await Task.Delay(200, token); // Do stuff
                } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                    throw;
                } catch (Exception) {
                    // Logging
                    throw;
                } finally {
                    batcher.Release();
                }
            }, token);
        }
```

Results:

```
Tasks: 25 RanToCompletion, 975 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 50 RanToCompletion, 950 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 75 RanToCompletion, 925 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 100 RanToCompletion, 900 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 120 RanToCompletion, 880 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 855 WaitingForActivation
Cancelling tasks
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 16 Canceled, 839 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 33 Canceled, 822 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 51 Canceled, 804 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 66 Canceled, 789 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 81 Canceled, 774 WaitingForActivation
Tasks: 145 RanToCompletion, 101 Canceled, 754 WaitingForActivation
```

As you can see, there's less tasks cancelled per second, than handled. At this rate, you'ld have the wait a full minute to get the 1000 pending tasks cancelled.

Making an alternative with new Task(), and calling Task.Start() will result in breaking the cancellation mechanic, instead throwing unhandled exceptions from each of the running tasks.

```cs
tasks.Where(t => t.Status < TaskStatus.Running)
     .Take(5 - tasks.Count(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Running))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(t => t.Start());

private static Task DoableWork(CancellationToken token)
        {
            return new Task(async () => {
                try {
                    await Task.Delay(200, token); // Do stuff
                } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
                    throw;
                } catch (Exception) {
                    // Logging
                    throw;
                }
            }, token);
        }
```

Comment: `t.Status < TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` smells. I don't think we are supposed to use enums like that.

Comment: An earlier version had a Task.WhenAll(). Either way, that's not the issue of this question. The thing is the tasks caught in the WaitAsync dealing with a cancellation, take longer than happyflow of the tasks. Try the program and do a cancel, and you'll see.

Comment: I'll try it. But meanwhile take a look at a better design for parallel throttling, that uses `SemaphoreSlim`: [Approaches for throttling asynchronous methods in C#](http://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp#semaphoreslim). Instead of starting 1000 hot tasks all at once, he starts them one by one **after** the `WaitAsync` of the semaphore.

Comment: Good point. Already was busy going down that route in a continuation to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I reduced the delay to 100 msec and still the cancelling is instantaneous ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/nh6pkp)). Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7.2, C# 7.3, Visual Studio 2017 15.9.11.

Comment: Couple of overloads of `WaitAsync` accept `CancellationToken` as a parameter, so by using one of them you can cancel `WaitAsync` with the same token you use for the tasks cancellation..

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, I found the issue. It's VS 2019 (or one of its settings) that's slowing down the exception handling significantly in debug mode. When I run the .exe directly, cancellation is instant as well.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov As stated in the question: cancellation token given to `WaitAsync` seems to freeze the application instead. Using .Net Core 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It's VS 2019 (or one of its settings) that's slowing down the exception handling significantly in debug mode. When I run the .exe directly, cancellation is instant.
Thanks to @TheodorZoulias for showing a failure to reproduce the issue.